# eclipse listener for main menu bar selections

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-pde

i am trying to capture user selections from the menu bar , for example if the user pressed File in the menu, my plug-in gonna print "File pressed". 
i figured out how to listen to view selections by IselectionService , but still has no clue how to do it with the main menu bars(or toolbars).

thanx for help

---

More details :

I gonna explain my problem a little bit more precisely :
I would like capture top-level menus actions and toolbar, the problem is I really don't know how to create and attach the listener.
Here is the `ISelectionListener` of the plugin.
My purpose is to listen to the workbench top-level menu selections and toolbar.
Thanx for help

```
// the listener we register with the selection service 
private ISelectionListener listener = new ISelectionListener() {
  public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {
    // we ignore our own selections
    if (sourcepart != SelectionView.this) {
      showSelection(sourcepart, selection);
    }
  }
};
...
...
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  ...
  getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(listener);
```

P.S : Most what I found about menu listener were SWT stuff for some view or windows I had created, thats not what I meant, I need listener to the main top level menu and toolbars in eclipse workbench.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location uri (which you can check with a [PluginSpy](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)), [you can add an handler](http://urbas.tk/index.php/2009/10/27/adding-menu-item-command-and-handler/) in order to react to that menu event.

Note: The [Menu Contribution article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Menu_Contributions#menu:) mentions the locationURI for:

- main menu is "`org.eclipse.ui.main.menu`"
- main toolbor is "`org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`"

Comment: hey, thanx for the fast reply :)

Comment: @amir: I have looked at your question again (and edited it actually), but have no new elements to add just now. Still looking.

Comment: thanx man :)....if you got some place or book to read it from (i searched a lot of books,still nothing), just let me know .

Answer (score 1):

Yuo could try to use the ICommandService:
with this service you can register an IExecutionListener.

This way you can track all the commands wich are executed but I'm afraid that this way you can't track the menu item that activated the command itself.

Hope it helps

Comment: i just wanna tell you i got some help from guys who made Smarttutor plugin, which excatly what i need. captures all the actions on the menus.

Comment: cerealk your right, it works. 
Iam looking now for main menu dropdown event and mouse hover event over menus and menuitems on eclipse. need help with that

Answer (score 0):

i just wanna tell you i got some help from guys who made Smarttutor plugin, which excatly what i need. captures all the actions on the menus. – amir farah 31 secs ago edit i just wanna tell you i got some help from guys who made Smarttutor plugin, which excatly what i need. captures all the actions on the menus.
 here is the website:code.google.com/p/smarttutor